# Git Branch changes by navigating into nested Directory

Tags: git

[image]

The Git folder contains a single project under version control.
I tried creating a new  branch (my first, other than master) from within the git folder using `git checkout -b <tests>` on the command line.
Now, when I type `git status`from the same location, I see: `On branch tests`.
However, when I cd into the Project folder "Bohnanza-Project" I am suddenly on branch main again!

I am new to git and assumed if i create and switch to a new branch while in any given directory, all subdirectories would also be associated with that new branch. ***Is it standard behavior to have a nested directory on a different git branch?***

Comment: Git doesn't store folders, only files; it's the OS that insists on folder-ization. If navigating into another folder in your OS causes Git to be on another *branch*, though, that means you're now in a different *repository*. Use `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to see where the top level of the current working tree is, and `git rev-parse --git-dir` to show where the Git directory holding the repository proper is (this may be relative to the top level, or absolute; recent Git versions added some flags to `git rev-parse` to make it more useful from scripts, so they don't have to mess with this).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it standard behavior to have a nested directory on a different git branch?

Yes, each repository, nested or not, have their own branch.

You would need an external third-party tool like, for instance, [Git X-Modules](https://gitmodules.com/) (free for now, while in beta in Q1 2022) to make a branch on the parent repository, and have it synchronized on all subrepos.

That would simplify [Cross-repository development](https://gitmodules.com/#server-side-solution_2).

[image: cross-repo branches]